# OWASP ZAP need to be integrated with Jackhammer as one of the scanners

Tags: owasp, zap

Jackhammer user guide explanation does not help, can anyone describe that process step by step. Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't a ZAP issue. But, following the guide https://jch.olacabs.com/userguide/adding_new_tool/, in step 3 you'd need to get the XML report from ZAP or interact with ZAP's web API to get alerts in json format and import them.

Comment: Thank you for response, I cant find the way to implement the run function as describe in step 3, I need to run zap in background, give target and get results of it, I cant find the documentation that describe that.

Comment: It depends on the level of detail and customization you need. If you need ZAP to login to you web apps then you need to interact with the API. If you just want point-and-shoot then you can just do something like: zap.bat -quickurl http://localhost/ -quickout C:\path\to\report.xml -daemon

Comment: You might also be interested in: https://github.com/Grunny/zap-cli